# chmod a folder on heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, flask, chmod

This question might seem a little stupid. I'm new to web development and I'm just writing a simple web app to start with. I'm using flask. The app gets some images from some other sites and save them to a folder 'savedimages'. The problem is after I deploy it on heroku, I can't open any of the images in the 'savedimages' folder. I guess this is because of the chmod of the folder isn't set to 755 or so... So how do I chmod this folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter that Heroku applications have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) -- that anything written to the filesystem can and will disappear without notice? If `savedimages` is a cache, this might be fine; if not, you might need to [store the data elsewhere](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Comment: When the app is active, you don't lose the content of your filesystem, but once you stop the instance, everything is gone. But this is not the problem here. What kind of error appears? What makes you say you "can't open any of the images in the 'savedimages' folder"?

Comment: I used urllib2 to get an image from the internet then save it in the 'savedimages' folder. But when I try going directly to the image, for example, http://example.com/savedimages/image1.jpg it says "Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server.

If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." I'm pretty sure the files are saved because I tested it on localhost. Also can you ssh into your heroku app and do stuff with the folders at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue most likely isn't that the permissions are off - it is most likely that Flask is mounted at the root of your application and you don't have any rules in your Flask app to serve the images.  Try adding a rule to your app:

```
@app.route("/savedimages/<picture>")
def display_picture(picture):
    return "The picture is: {}".format(picture)
```

If it displays, then simply change your return to use [`flask.send_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_file):

```
file_name = werkzeug.security.safe_join("/path/to/savedimages", picture)
return send_file(file_name)
```

Comment: thanks. this works brillant! just a note. it's actually werkzeug.security.safe_join . but thank you!